# How can I fix this "Not a SELECTed expression" error using Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, orm, hql

I have the following method performing a Hibernate query:

```
    @Override
    public List<ErrorsDTOEntity> getErrors(double daysPrevious, double hoursToShow) {
        try {
            Query query = getSession().createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT NEW com.mydomain.esb.jpa.dto.ErrorsDTOEntity(ee, ec.message) "
                    + "FROM ErrorsEntity ee, EventCodeEntity ec "
                    + "WHERE ee.responseTime > (sysdate - (" + daysPrevious + " + " + hoursToShow + "/24)) "
                    + "AND ee.responseTime < (sysdate - " + daysPrevious + ") "
                    + "AND ee.serviceResponseCode = ec.code "
                    + "GROUP BY ee.domainName, ee.serviceName, ec.message, ee.serviceErrorCount, ee.errorTimestamp, "
                    + "ee.deviceName, ee.servErrId, ee.serviceResponseCode, ee.elapsedTime, ee.forwardTime, "
                    + "ee.responseCompletionTime, ee.responseSizeAverage, ee.requestSizeAverage, ee.responseTime "
                    + "ORDER BY ee.domainName, ec.message");

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<ErrorsDTOEntity> services = (List<ErrorsDTOEntity>) query.list();
            return services;

        } catch (HibernateException hex) {
            hex.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return null;
    }
}
```

This throws the following error:

```
ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression
```

This is due to the `ee.domainName` in the `ORDER BY` clause but I don't understand why and what I can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think this is due to the use of `DISTINCT` in the query.